# Flutter payment

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, square, in-app-subscription

I am building a flutter app in which premium users can access premium data after purchasing monthly or yearly plan. Premium contents are basically more data and features that are restricted to free users. After reading some confusing posts and policy, I would really appreciate if someone could explain some of the available payment options for Flutter in this case. I tried to use square payment but based on some of the posts, I cannot use square payment for digital content. Is that correct? I can't find any concrete information on this and would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use GooglePay by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_pay).

ApplePay by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_apple_pay).

Stripe by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment).

or Braintree by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree).

hope it will helps.

Comment: thank you for your response but don't apple pay and google pay charge 30%? Also, isn't Stripe same as Square? Not sure about Braintree.